# How to search by MIGRATED questions, or drive-by questions?

Tags: support

Is there any way to search for questions that have been *migrated to* WPSE? Additionally, is there any way to search for questions that have been asked, but have received no follow-up from the user who asked the question?

#### Edit

Ultimately, I'm looking for a way to find questions by "users" such as this one:
[Facebook Share button wont recognize embedded video](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8368/facebook-share-button-wont-recognize-embedded-video)

e.g. "user1234"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have more than 10,000 reputation, you gain access to various moderator tools (accessible from the "mod" link at the top of the page.

The Moderator Tools page has a separate tab that lists all posts migrated to and away from the site:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/migrated/here

Comment: I *do* have Moderator Tools, but the link isn't quite as... *exposed* as it is for actual Moderators: **Review** link -> **Tools** tab -> **Migrated**. It links [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tools?s=1&tab=migrated&daterange=today).

Comment: Glad to know. Downside of never having seen the non-moderator Mod Tools ... :-(